# Mathematical and real analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $d(A,B)=\inf\{d(x,y)\mid y\in B, x\in A\}$ that $A$ and $B$ are subset of metric space $X$.
If $d(A,B)\leq 1$, then $d(x,y)\leq 1$ for every $x\in A, y\in B$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please edit your question and restate it clearly. Look at the suggestion in the answer. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: No, it is not true. By example let the sets $A=(-1,1)$ and $B=(2,3)$, then $d(A,B)=1$ for the standard metric in $\Bbb R$ but $d(0,5/2)=5/2>1$.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is "If the infimum of some set of real numbers is less than $1$, then are all elements of that set less than $1$?" The answer to that is no in general, although for some specific $A$ and $B$ it is true.

Comment: I'd say that the question asks about *distances*: if the infimum of all the distances between the elements of two sets is less than one, then  is the distance between any two elements, each in one of those two sers,  less than one"?

Comment: @DonAntonio This is how I read the question: $\{d(x,y)\mid y\in B, x\in A\}$ is a set of real numbers, and it has an infimum which we assume is less than (or equal to) $1$. Does that mean that every $d(x, y)$ in that set is less than (or equal to) $1$?

Comment: @Ar I agree with and your answer, though perhaps a specific example would help the OP...and it is pretty easy to come up with one, for example: $\;A:=\left\{\,\left(x,\,\frac1x\right)\;/\;x>0\,\right\}\;,\;\;B:=\left\{\,(0,y)\;/\;y\in\Bbb R\,\right\}$